# Python MIT 6.00.1X

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a code and I think its about done I'm just having one problem when my loop runs and I remove something out of the list it skips the next variable in the list and I cant figure out how to make it not skip it. I'm guessing because the next variable is 0 and the loop is thinking it already did 0. Is there a way to fix this. Code below

```
def f(i):
    return i + 2
def g(i):
    return i > 5


def applyF_filterG(L, f, g):
    """
    Assumes L is a list of integers
    Assume functions f and g are defined for you. 
    f takes in an integer, applies a function, returns another integer 
    g takes in an integer, applies a Boolean function, 
        returns either True or False
    Mutates L such that, for each element i originally in L, L contains  
        i if g(f(i)) returns True, and no other elements
    Returns the largest element in the mutated L or -1 if the list is empty
    """
    for i in L:
        if g(f(i)) == False:
           L.remove(i)
    return max(L)


L = [0, -10, 5, 6, -4]
print(applyF_filterG(L, f, g))
print(L)
```

Comment: Pretty sure you are breaking the honor code by posting here, there are numerous forums provided by MIT to get help, I would suggest you use those in place of posting here.

Answer (score 2):

Try copying all the values of L to L_temp so that you don't mess up L when going over the iterations and to avoid skipping the values when mutating the list. Should be something like this

```
def applyF_filterG(L, f, g):

    L_temp = L[:]    
    for i in L_temp:
        if g(f(i)) == False:
           L.remove(i)
    if len(L) == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return max(L)
```

Answer (score 2):

More succinctly:

```
max(x for x in L if f(g(x)))
```

To mutate the list:

```
L[:] = [x for x in L if f(g(x))]
return max(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def applyF_filterG(L, f, g):
    l = []
    if len(L) > 0:
        for i in L:
            if (g(f(i)) == True):
                l.append(i)
        L[:] = l
        if len(L) > 0:
            return max(L)
        else:
            return -1
    else:
        L[:] = l
        return -1
```

this code works